# IHttpModule Not Loaded upon Bootstrap in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to create a URL rewriting module for ASP.NET.

Here's how I declared it:

```
namespace A.Webrole 
public class UrlRewriterHttpModule : IHttpModule{...
```

and I said

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRewriterHttpModule" type="A.Webrole.UrlRewriterHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

in the `Web.config` file.

Then I put breakpoints inside `public void Init(HttpApplication context)` method of `UrlRewriterHttpModule` however no breakpoints stopped the execution.

Then I just renamed the class to a dummy name and restarted the application again, no exceptions are thrown class not found etc.

Do you have any ideas why this might not be even loading the http module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you're doing to test it. If you're using Visual Studio's built in web server, or IIS6 it requires a different config setting;

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
          <add name="UrlRewriterHttpModule" type="A.Webrole.UrlRewriterHttpModule"/>
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Of course, you could just use the MS supplied [rewriter](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) if it were suitable and save some time :)

Comment: actually my rewriter would be complicated and given rule mechanism does not fit my needs. should I also keep already existing setting at the same time?

Comment: Yes, keep the existing one so it works on IIS7. If you're only developing for IIS7 then take a look at IIS Express, it'll make development easier for you.